# How to get ADB path programmatically?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, plugins, adb

I am developing a plugin for Android Studio. For that, I need adb support.

If the development machine configured with ADb (setting environment variable), it is easy to execute commands. But if the system is not configured with ADB, I need the root path for ADB.

So how to find the ADB path that Android Studio is using by programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following heuristics:

```
    Project currentProject = anActionEvent.getProject();
    String localProperties = currentProject.getBasePath() + "/local.properties";

    try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(localProperties)) {

        Properties prop = new Properties();

        prop.load(input);

        String sdkDir = prop.getProperty("sdk.dir");

        String adbPath = sdkDir + "/platform-tools/adb";

        // do somethign
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // some error
    }
```